# Excel vectorized formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What happen if range of cells is used as parametr of function instead of single value ?

For example: SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4," ","")

Is it work fine if results of function is nested inside other function which take vector or range(formula above returns range/ vector of results, one per cell)?

Is it connected with ctrl + shift + enter forms ?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example which will help you to understand substitute will work on a range based on the usage and combination.

**In A Column**

Good

Wood

World

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:A3))
```

Result will be 13

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,"o","")))
```

Result will be 8

***Note:-***

If I add this in comment then it will not be easy to read.